# Child theme:Loading js files

Tags: themes

I'm creating a twitter bootstrapped child theme based on TwentyEleven.I want to load bootstrap.js so I've written the following line to get the bootstrap.js file but it is not returning correct path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php dirname( bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ) ?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The path I'm getting:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/codemasala/style.css/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
```

The path I should get:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/codemasala/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is because `bloginfo()` echoes the data where `get_bloginfo()` doesn't. So `dirname()` isn't really used. Using `stylesheet_directory` is better though since that won't need the dirname() call at all.

You could also use the wrapper `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which adheres to the filter `stylesheet_directory_uri`.

This is your code corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

**However**, the "WordPress-way" of adding scripts is by adding it the script queue. Doing it this way will ensure that your script is always loaded after it's dependencies and it will also make it possible for other scripts to use your script as a dependency.

To add a script to WordPress's queue you use [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). See the examples. Below is a script which should work for you. Add it to your theme's functions.php file.

```
function enqueue_bootstrap() {
  wp_enqueue_script('twitter-bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_bootstrap');
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's a bad advice in so many directions...

Comment: In what way? As I understood it, he asked what he did wrong. Sure he should use `wp_enqueue_script()`, but that wasn't really the question.

Comment: Then simply show him how to make it better.

Comment: I'm a Wordpress newbie so can you tell where I should put that enqueue function?

Comment: Sorry! It will work if you add that to your `.../wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/functions.php` file.

Comment: @kaiser Updated. Overall betterified answer.

Comment: Upvoted answer.